# Error breaking out of a try/catch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

As i was programming a NPM package, i came to need of a `try{}catch{}` statement, but error sometimes breaks out of `try{}` part and terminates the entire process.

As `try{}catch{}` is used to catch errors from `try{}` part and handle them with the `catch{}` part, I expected that the error will be caught and passed to `catch{}`, but when a function returns an error using `return`, not `throw` statement, the error breaks out. I tried different call methods, such as `.call(...)` or `.apply(...)`, but the problem persists.

This passes:

```js
let result;

let throwError = () => throw new Error("I didn't break out!");

try {
  let res = throwError();
  result = res;
} catch(err) {
  result = {
    message: err.message,
    name: err.name
  }
}

result; // {name: "Error", message: "I didn't break out!"}
```

This fails:

```js
let result;

let returnError = () => new Error("I broke out!")

try {
  let res = returnError(); // Error: I broke out!
  result = res;
} catch(err) {
  result = {
    message: err.message,
    name: err.name
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your first code block supposed to be calling `throwError()`.  Right now, it's calling `returnError()`.

Comment: Uh, *why* are you returning an error object instead of throwing an exception? Just don't do that.

Comment: @Bergi As I commented on an [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76798717/22217619), the `returnError` or `throwError` function is *provided by user* (I don't know the contents) and I wanted to make sure that my `try{}catch{}` won't be broken by user.

Comment: @MfyDev Well you are not responsible for broken code written by the user of your library. Document that the provided function should throw an exception, and handle only that case. Do not accept returned errors, that's just a weird pattern. If you absolutely want to, check the return value and print a warning to the devtools that the programmer made a mistake and should fix it.

Comment: It's not clear though why the returned value "breaks out" or "terminates the entire process". There must be something else going on. What is your code normally doing with `result` (on the happy path), what kind of value do you expect to get returned?

Comment: @Bergi If the function succeeds, the returned value (`result`) is forwarded back to user.

Comment: @MfyDev Then there's no problem. Maybe the user meant to return an error object. Maybe the user failed to throw an exception. You can't know. Either way, it's not your problem - you clearly document that to signal a problem, the user-provided function must throw an exception, and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem here. If you want to catch an error being throw, `try/catch` will do that. If you want to catch an error being returned, you need a different check for that.

```js
let result;

let returnError = () => new Error("I broke out!")

try {
  let res = returnError();
  
  if (res instanceof Error) {
    throw res;
  }

  result = res;
} catch(err) {
  result = {
    message: err.message,
    name: err.name
  }
}
```

Comment: Though in the above code, since you control the `returnError`, the `try/catch` isn't needed at all since the function will never throw. Just use `if/else`

Comment: In my real application code,  I cannot control `returnError`. It's provided by user.

Comment: Then my example above is exactly what you want :)